# A generalization of Hurwitz zeta function

Tags: summation, special-functions, zeta-functions

Hurwitz zeta function has definition

$$\zeta(s,q) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(q+n)^s}$$

Consider generalization

$$\tilde{\zeta}(s,q, t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(q+n^t)^s}$$

Is $\tilde{\zeta}(s,q, t)$ known, at least for some $t \ne 1$, in closed form or in terms of known special function?

Comment: In both case, use the binomial series to relate it to $\zeta(s)$ and obtain the meromorphic continuation and possibly some special values. For $q$ rational $\zeta(s,q)$ is more special because you can relate it directly to a finite sum of Dirichlet L-functions.

Comment: I believe the closed form of your function (for positive integer values of $s$) comes from differentiating the sum  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{q+n^t}$  with respect to $q$ some number of times. I also believe the closed form of  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{q+n^t}$ can be obtained by Fourier Series or Poisson Summation Formula in some clever way.

Comment: @VivekKaushik I don't think so, except for $t \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$ where you can express $\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{1}{q+n^t}$ in term of $\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}( qe^{2i \pi k/t})$

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I apologize for making a wrong comment.